# make a weak relationship using doctrine and symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

what im trying to do is a weak relationship between my `User` table and my `Confirmation` table, being `Confirmation` weak of `User`. To represent it, my schema is as follows:

```
User:
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: User
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    username:
      type: string(50)
      notnull: true
    name:
      type: string(50)
      notnull: true
        .
        .
        .
  indexes:
    myindex1:
      fields:
        username:
          sorting: ASC
          length: 50
      type: unique
  relations:
    Confirmation:
      foreignType: one
  attributes:
    export: all
    validate: true

Confirmation:
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: Confirmation
  columns:
    user_id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
    hash:
      type: string(64)
      notnull: true
  relations:
    User:
      local: user_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
      foreignType: one
```

When running the command `$ php symfony doctrine:build --all --no-confirmation`, i got this error in the output:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'id' doesn't exist in table. Failing Query: "CREATE TABLE Confirmation (user_id BIGINT, hash VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, created_at DATETIME NOT NULL, updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL, INDEX id_idx (id), PRIMARY KEY(user_id)) ENGINE = INNODB". Failing Query: CREATE TABLE Confirmation (user_id BIGINT, hash VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, created_at DATETIME NOT NULL, updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL, INDEX id_idx (id), PRIMARY KEY(user_id)) ENGINE = INNODB
```

so, it seems doctrine is generating an index over a field that was not defined (`id`) as you can see in `INDEX id_idx (id)`. Why is doctrine generating this index? how can i model what i want?

doctrine documentation is not very extensive in relationships matters, any link to a good documentation site would be very appreciated too...

Thanks in advance for any help!!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, Doctrine will automatically add a column "id" per default to (all of) your table(s).

This behaviour is documented several times, and you can configure this column :

- [Default identifier options](http://www.symfonyreference.com/databases-yml)
- http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/pl/configuration:defaults-attributes:default-added-auto-id
- [3.) Removed id column as it is automatically added if no primary key is defined.](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/pl/introduction-to-models)

**But**, i'm sorry, i'dont know, if there is a way to disable this feature.